# NGINX problem, I don't have the same result with simple location and location with variable

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I have a simple react application and I have some problem with my locations nginx configuration

```
location /dpo-portal/ {
    proxy_pass http://dpo-portal:5000/;
}
location /dpo-portal2/ {
    set $dpo dpo-portal:5000;
    proxy_pass http://$dpo/;
}
```

It seems that JS isn't load with `dpo-portal2`,

I would like to understand when i use a variable if I have to add some configuration

[firefox debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gv2gn.png)

Comment: See [the section: "When variables are used in proxy_pass"](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass). In your second case, the URI passed to `dpo-portal:5000` is **always** `/`.